Sequence of pronouns
In a series of first, second, and third person pronouns in a sentence containing, she/he, you, and I, what is the correct sequence order? Which of the following sentence is correct?

I, you and he will watch football.
You, he and I will watch football.
He, you and I will watch football.


It's traditionally regarded as correct to put yourself last, though it's very common nowadays to hear "Me and John did this" (which is wrong on two counts!).

There's some support for you first, I last, others in the middle - see this question on English Language Learners - but also a lot of scope for doing what sounds best. Some sources recommend starting with I or we if you're apologising, but I'm not sure that can be considered a grammatical rule, rather than just a recognition that you can do it whatever order seems best.

It also sounds clumsy having so many pronouns. "He, you, and I" is usually simplified to just "We"

@Greybeard "You, they, and I."

Theoretically, in rhetoric, you address your audience directly and first. You refer to third parties next, and finally include yourself: "You, they, and I will march on the palace!" -> "You, our allies, and I will march on the palace!"
